# Why is "His Dark Materials" by Philip Pullman considered by some as anti religion?

Tags: religion, his-dark-materials

I've read somewhere that *His Dark Materials* by Philip Pullman are attacked by many religious figures. I have only seen the movie "Golden Compass" but I would like to find out some more information as to why people would think that this series is anti-religion? And is it targeted by Catholic Church only or other Churches are attacking Pullman's work as well?

Comment: It becomes a whole lot clearer when you read the two other books.

Comment: The *Golden Compass* doesn't really say much about religion; the *Subtle Knife* gives a few hints that the books will have something about religion; and in the *Amber Spyglass*...

Comment: The movie whitewashes most of that...

Comment: Even *The Golden Compass* had enough anti-religious content that I didn't even bother reading the other books. It's not that I want religion in the books I read — the *Pern* books famously totally leave out that aspect of society, and I love them — but Pullman just gets so annoying about it.

Comment: @Martha the movie is much less anti-religious than the book "the Northern Lights".

Answer (score 59, accepted):

The author himself said, ["My books are about killing God."](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/His_Dark_Materials#Controversies) His work also appears to be anti-established religion, e.g. in this quote:

> *That's what the Church does, and every church is the same: control, destroy, obliterate every good feeling*

In addition, one of the main characters gives up being a nun and states, *"the Christian religion... is a very powerful and convincing mistake, that's all"* (see above link).

However, for both quotes it is important to realise that the author has stated that readers should not equate his characters' opinions with his own.

Comment: From Pullman's own word's, one could answer as "Because the author himself said that they are".

Comment: As Mike Scott says, the movies are toned down. Moreover, the anti-religious topics are more developed in the other two books.

Comment: I never understood how people could consider that they *weren't*. The final book was so hilariously and blatantly anti-religion that it pretty much ruined the story for me...Not because I'm religious (I'm not) but because the huge chip on his shoulder and his preachy prose were so off-putting.

Comment: It never struck me as anti-religion, but anti-establishmet.  They seemed very much in favor of a personal relationship with God on one's own terms.

Answer (score 17):

The religious elements were toned down considerably in the movie, for American consumption. The books are very hostile to organised religion, and Pullman is promoting the idea of the "Republic of Heaven"; a religion with no central authority figure such as God.